# Numerical method for finding root of of a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ for $n>1$.

Tags: numerical-methods, roots

Let us consider a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ of $n$ real variables say, $\>x_1,x_2,...,x_n$.
Now I want to find the root of $f$, means I want to find a approx. point $(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ such that $$f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=0.$$ Is there any numerical method for finding a root of the above function?
In case of $n=1,\>\>$ I know several numerical methods like Bisection method, Newton Raphson, fixed point iteration, etc. But for $n>1$ is there any suitable method to compute the root?
Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Is gradient descent on $|f|$ a possibility? I think it won't work in any cases, as in could converge to non-zero local minima, but may be helpful if you have some idea of where the zeros may be

Comment: Do you have two points with opposite signs in their values? Then you can apply any bracketing method like bisection or Brent on the segment connecting these points.